# Where does Windows 8 keep Roaming App data files?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, appdata, roaming

I'm going through the Windows 8 tutorial on managing app lifecycle and state and the tutorial goes through the code for creating roaming appdata for my app which allows me to keep data for my app across sessions - so if I closed (fully close) my app, the next time I run it that data can be loaded back.

Where does Windows actually keep this in file? I cannot locate it in C:\users\username\appData\roaming

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> C:\Users\*user name*\AppData\Local\Packages\*Package Number*\RoamingState

It would be easier to simply debug your application and look at an instance of this to get the location:

```
Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer roamingFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder;
```

or more exactly:

```
var path = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder.Path
```

Comment: Thanks - how do I find my package number?

Comment: Debug into your application and look at the value returned by `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder;`

Comment: I tried (using javascript):

`var roamingFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder;
            console.log(roamingFolder);` 

however it's not letting the program run as it calls the debugger straight away. I think maybe I'm misunderstanding what you mean by "Debug into my application"?

Comment: Hard to tell why that is.  Can't you just do the first line and set a breakpoint on it and view the value using the debugger?

Comment: ah, it's errorring out because current.roamingFolder is not capitalised. However all I get returned in the console is: `[object Windows.Storage.StorageFolder]`

Comment: Look at the `Path` property.  Like `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder.Path`

Comment: Excellent:

`C:\Users\Arvin\AppData\Local\Packages\1be986de-f138-4135-b427-8041dfef87e6_1em60301wsydt\RoamingState`

Thank you very much

Comment: But curiously that folder is empty?

Comment: How did you populate it?  Could you link the tutorial?

Comment: Tutorial: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh986966.aspx)

The code is: `var appData = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current;
      var roamingSettings = appData.roamingSettings;
      roamingSettings.values["userName"] = nameInput.value;`

Comment: That would be because you're not storing a file, you're storing a setting.  Notice how to get the roaming folder we have to explicitly say we want a folder.  Otherwise you're just sticking it in the settings object.  I'm not sure where that is stored in the filesystem.

Comment: ah i see. well I guess the more important question is how would I go about deleting that setting without coding it? Let's say for some reason someone using my app has run into a bug that caused my app not to work and they want to reset the settings

Comment: I'm going to guess it's located here: Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder , but I can't really say since I'm on my win 7 computer.  If you're trying to test and want to reset you can just do a clean/rebuild and you should wipe it out.

Comment: Ok, there is a "Settings" folder within my package directory. Deleting its contents has reset all of my app to default. Thanks for your help!